# jQuery load ajax after an element

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

html code block:

**index.php html block:**

```
<div class="row">
    <button id="addoption" type="submit">add</button>
</div>
```

**external.php**

```
<div class="well" id="optionform" >hello</div>
```

I want add `div#optionform` (in externall.php) after `div.row` in index.php

I try this:

```
$('#addoption').on('click',function(){
    $(this).parent().after().load( "externall.php #optionform" );
});
```

It add but also remove `div.row`. (it replace div.row with `div#optionform`)

I only want add `div#optionform` html block after `div.row`.

how can I do it?

I want this:

```
<div class="row">
    <button id="addoption" type="submit"></i>add</button>
</div>
<div class="well" id="optionform" >hello</div>
```

Comment: Did you try .append() method in jQuery? it will not remove the existing element but insert the new content at the bottom of selected parent.

Comment: Your valid is invalid. You've got a closing `</i>` but no opening one.

Comment: Hi Elize, are you trying to add the value after you click on the button?

Comment: @AalokMishra and did you try to look at API what `.after()` does?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#addoption').on('click',function(){
    $(document).load( "externall.php #optionform" );  
    $("#optionform").insertAfter($(this).parent());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

append does not work. it replace too

finally I solved it by this way:

```
$('#addoption').on('click',function(){
        var response;
        $.ajax({ type: "GET",   
            url: "externall.php",   
            async: false,
            success : function(text)
            {
                response= text;
            }
        });
        $(this).parent().after(response);
    });
```

Comment: be aware, that `async` is deprecated, so it would be better to store `var $parent = $(this).parent();` and put `$parent.after(text);` in your `success` .. no need for response variable and no need for async too

Answer (score -1):

I'm not entirely sure how your external.php is setup without seeing the code so I can't tell you how to grab that data.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var optionscount=0;
    $( "#addoption" ).click(function() {
       $( "#options" ).append("<div class=\"well\" id=\"optionform("+optionscount+"\">hello</div>");
    });
</script>

<div class="row" id="options">
    <button id="addoption" type="submit"></i>add</button>
</div>
```

Comment: He wants to load `external.php` not just some HTML. And wants it after `div.row` not inside.

Answer (score -1):

As @Alok Mishra mentioned you can use `.append()` to add an element under of an specified element. You use it like:

```
$('#parent').append( $('#child') );
```

So you could write:

```
$('#addoption').click(function(){
  $(document).load("external.php #optionform");
  $('.row').parent().append( $('#optionform') );
})
```

**Note:** I spelled the `external.php` with only on `l`. I thought it was a misspelling from sour side.

Comment: He want his form out of div#row, your code insert the form into the div.

Comment: but he wants to add content BELOW / AFTER, not as a CHILD

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I forgot the parent() ;)